Converting the Dimensions of a Playing Card to Pixels (2.5 inches x 3.5 inches)
How do I convert the dimensions of a playing card (2.5 inches x 3.5 inches) to pixels?
How do I do that?
My resolution screen size is: 1280 x 720.
I’m not using it on mobile.
I just want to create stuff on it.
As a visual aid.
Is someone able to help me figure this out?
This is too big though:
240 pixels
336 pixels
Image

You want to learn CSS values and units, particulary length units. Fun fact: there are only 3 cuntries in the world that use inches -- United States, Liberia, and Myanmar.

Sadly CSS in (inch) unit isn't going to help you on a typical screen [it can be useful for printing]. If you are using just the screen you have access to then maybe a ruler will be your best aid - measure the actual width/height of the viewport you are using then use %s (and don't zoom!).

In CSS you can use absolute lengths. So you don’t need to convert anything to pixels, just specify your sizes using in.


body {
  margin: 0.2in;
  background-color: silver;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2in;
}
.cards .red {
  color: #d90000;
}
.cards > span {
  width: 2.5in;
  height: 3.5in;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 0.1in;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.3in;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.1in;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.cards > span > span:nth-child(1) {
  align-self: start;
}
.cards > span > span:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 1in;
  align-self: center;
}
.cards > span > span:nth-child(3) {
  align-self: end;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
<div class="cards">
  <span class="black">
    <span>A<br>♠️</span>
    <span>♠️</span>
    <span>A<br>♠️</span>
  </span>
  <span class="black">
    <span>A<br>♣️</span>
    <span>♣️</span>
    <span>A<br>♣️</span>
  </span>
  <span class="red">
    <span>A<br>♦️</span>
    <span>♦️</span>
    <span>A<br>♦️</span>
  </span>
  <span class="red">
    <span>A<br>♥️</span>
    <span>♥️</span>
    <span>A<br>♥️</span>
  </span>
</div>



As @AHaworth indicates, the catch is that the rendered size on a screen will be only a rough approximation — it will not be perfectly accurate. When rendering to a screen, browsers use a fixed value of ninety-six CSS pixels per CSS inch, but a CSS pixel does not render at exactly one ninety-sixth of an inch on all screens. Users can typically also zoom a page within their browser and/or operating system, and the amount of zoom is not available within CSS. So your results will be approximate only. On my laptop screen, the rendered size of the cards in the snippet above is a bit smaller than a real playing card (the width is just under two inches). But it may be a close enough approximation for your scenario, and certainly a lot easier than messing about with resolutions, conversions and media queries.

Using in (inch) as a unit on my laptop screen gives a card which is way out of the actual specified inches dimension. I think the only way to go is to physically measure on the actual screen in use and set CSS width/height in relation to that. in (inch) can work OK on printers apparently.
